# iOS - Sending Latitude and Longitude to Server when app is not running (app is in suspended state)

Tags: ios, background

I want to implement a scenario to update latitude and longitude to a server when the iOS app is not working or in a suspended state.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this question about android or ios ?

Comment: do you want know is an ios app is not running?

Comment: @a_local_nobody question is about iOS. But, please let me know how to achieve it in Android also.

Comment: those are two separate questions entirely

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios in this case, I am assuming that the user has removed an app from a background, so it is not running.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Please tell me about iOS.

Answer (score 0):

See the Apple Docs on [background location tracking.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background?language=objc) there’s different ways to do it depending on how accurate and what purpose you want the data. The significant change service is a good starting point. It wakes your app with new coordinates as the user moves to a new area.